# Routing not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Below code displays a list of items.

**App.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <AppContext.Provider value={{ state: this.state }}>
            <ItemList />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/detail/:id" component={ItemDetail} />
              <Route exact={true} path="/" component={ItemList} />
            </Switch>
          </AppContext.Provider>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

**ItemList.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {context => {
          return context.state.itemList.map(item => {
            return (
                <Link key={item.id} to={`/detail/${item.id}`}>
                  <p>{item.id}</p>
                </Link>
            );
          });
        }}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
```

**ItemDetail.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default function ItemDetail(props) {
  return <div>Item detail</div>;
}
```

on clicking any item from the list, item detail should be displayed (from ItemDetail component). problem is only url is getting changed to /detail/id, but component is not getting changed  ie not changing to ItemDetail.js

Comment: Hi @ram! Are you seeing any errors in console?

Comment: does `ItemDetail` also need to render an `AppContext.Consumer` element?

Comment: I see no errors.

Comment: ItemDetail need not render an AppContext.Consumer element. though i may need to fetch id from url and get item detail data from api for displaying item detail.

Comment: You are rendering twice `ItemList` component, one outside router `Switch` component and one inside. Are you sure you are not seeing the `ItemDetail` item at the bottom of the `ItemList` that is placed outside of the router?

Comment: I am able to see ItemDetail at the bottom.